# How to use a string to call a queryset in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have 2 models which have foreign keys referencing a third model. Its something like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

class Model1(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='m1_related')

class Model2(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='m2_related')
```

Now, lets say I have an instance of `Foo` and a string which is either `'m1'` or `'m2'`. How can I use this string to call the appropriate queryset using the related names?

Something like this:

```
my_str = 'm1'
foo.my_str+'_related'.objects.all()
```

Obviously, the above code is just wrong in so many ways, but hopefully that makes it clear. I don't want to use if else conditions for this, as the number of models will be a lot, and all their related names will follow the same pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getattr(..)` to obtain the name of an attribute, like:

```
my_str = 'm1'
getattr(foo, my_str+'_related').objects.all()
```

A call to `getattr(x, 'y')` is equivalent to `x.y` (note that in `getattr(..)` the `'y`' is a string. So we can use `getattr(..)` obtain the attribute.